# Custom Maven Plugin doesn't resolve parent POM when used in another clean project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-plugin, dependency-management

The I am attempting to use my custom Maven plugin in a completely new system.  It appears to not resolving the parent POM used by the custom Maven plugin.

I have tried several things but I am at a loss.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

> **Update**
>
> This is is very strange.... this error only occurs when I clean my local repository (simulating a clean system such as a new developer or integration system).  If I run the 'mvn -U install' command immediately again (without changing the command at all) then it builds successfully!
>
> This screams 'transitive dependency' but how do I find such an infraction?
>
> **Update**
>
> I am thinking that this is a bug in Maven.  The reactor doesn't find the parent POM even though it is located in the same project!  What do you all think?

Custom Plugin POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my.org</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-java-with-foundation</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>my.org.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

</project>
```

Error Trace:

```
[ERROR] Plugin my.org.maven:maven-plugin:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for my.org.maven:maven-plugin:jar:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact my.org:parent-java-with-foundation:pom:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin my.org.maven:maven-plugin:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for my.org.maven:maven-plugin:jar:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for my.org.maven:maven-plugin:jar:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:108)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact my.org:parent-java-with-foundation:pom:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:817)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:669)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:361)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact my.org:parent-java-with-foundation:pom:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact my.org:parent-java-with-foundation:pom:11.1.1.8-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:449)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: The parent pom must be available in either the repository, at the specified location using relativePath or in the default location (..\pom.xml). Is it?

Comment: It is located in the companies Nexus repository.  A relative path doesn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: Updated with more information regarding predictability.

Comment: Is the parent POM an independent project or a submodule of the current reactor build?

Comment: It is an independent project.  I am deploying the "my.org:parent-java-with-foundation:pom" by itself.  The parent project that is using the 
"my.org.maven:maven-plugin" has the same parent POM.

The parent POM is merely a common set of dependencies and plugin executions such as javadoc, unit test, etc..

It isn't a submodule.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for this. If the parent POM isn't part of the reactor (= the current build) and you deleted your local cache, then Maven has to find it somewhere.

If you have a company wide repository, make sure that this version is available from there. Make especially sure that you can download `SNAPSHOT` versions (some repos can disable that plus you can configure Maven never to download snapshots from certain repos).

If you don't have a company wide repository, then you need to run `mvn install` in the parent project, first. Maven doesn't try to find missing pieces anywhere on your hard disk.

Comment: It is totally in the company repo, has proper access rights, and exists at the right coordinates.  It is strange that if I just hit Up and Enter (in the console) triggering the same build again.. it works just fine!

Comment: Try to run `mvn` with `-X` to get debug output. Search for the artifact ID; maybe you can find something.